# How do I produce the required XML output grouping and sorting by like source nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

Given this source XML:

```
<output>
   <report>
      <C01>
         <InvID>001</InvID>
         <Daily>
            <row id="0000">1</row>
            <row id="0001">2</row>
            <row id="0002">5</row>
            <row id="0003">4</row>
         </Daily>
      </C01>
      <C02>
         <InvID>002</InvID>
         <Daily>
            <row id="0000">4</row>
            <row id="0001">3</row>
            <row id="0002">2</row>
            <row id="0003">5</row>
         </Daily>
      </C02>
      <C03>
         <InvID>001</InvID>
         <Daily>
            <row id="0000">3</row>
            <row id="0001">7</row>
            <row id="0002">2</row>
            <row id="0003">4</row>
         </Daily>
      </C03>
   <report>
<output>
```

How can I produce this output:

```
<Data invID=001>
   <Value>1</Value>
   <Value>2</Value>
   <Value>5</Value>
   <Value>4</Value>
   <Value>3</Value>
   <Value>7</Value>
   <Value>2</Value>
   <Value>4</Value>
</Data>
<Data invID=002>
   <Value>4</Value>
   <Value>3</Value>
   <Value>2</Value>
   <Value>5</Value>
</Data>
```

I have been trying to use something like this as the basis, but it feels all wrong:

```
<xsl:template match="output/report">
   <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'C') and InvID != '']">
      <xsl:sort select="InvID" />
      <xsl:element name="Data">
         <xsl:attribute name="invID">
            <xsl:value-of select="InvID" />
         </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to aggregate all items that share a common `InvID`, output a single `Data` element for that group of source elements, and then output all of their `row` element values into children of that `Data` element (`Value`).

Can this be done in XPath 1.0?

Comment: Look up _Muenchian grouping_, it's the standard approach for this in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Though your expected output looks at odds with your description - you've grouped the C01 and C02 rows together rather than the C01 and C03 ones.  And also you'll need to wrap the output in a single top-level element to make it well-formed.

Comment: @IanRoberts Good catch...fixed.

Comment: @IanRoberts I get the gist of the method, and I read some before.  But what I couldn't find is an example of one that _does not_ have a non-static element name.  I.e. the examples I find have a fixed node structure, but the main node I need to group around is variable...`C01`, `C02`, `C03`, etc.  No idea how to key that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggest in my comment, the technique you're looking for is called *Muenchian grouping*.  This works by defining a *key* that groups related nodes together, then using a trick with `generate-id` or `count` to construct a node set consisting of one "representative" node for each group.  In your case, since the nodes you want to group together have different names you have to be a bit more creative with the matching patterns but the principle is the same:

```
<xsl:key name="groupByInv" match="*[InvID]" use="InvID" />
```

Here I'm interested in any element (regardless of name) that has an `InvID` child, and I want to group them together based on the `InvID` value.  Now the actual grouping is straightforward:

```
<xsl:template match="output/report">
  <xsl:for-each select="*[InvID][generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('groupByInv', InvID)[1])]">
    <Data invID="{InvID}">
      <!-- process all the rows under all the elements in the current group -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupByInv', InvID)/Daily/row" />
    </Data>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ian.  I get into XML/XPath so infrequently these days...  Works like a charm!